# Is it possible to specify SFTP options in "sftp://" URI?

Tags: openssh, sftp, uri

Is it possible to specify any [SFTP options](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sftp.1.html) inside an URI of the form `sftp://...`?

I am particularly interested in being able to supply the `-4` option to enforce IPv4 when using a [Nautilus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNOME_Files) bookmark in `~/.config/gtk-3.0/bookmarks` on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those aren't "SFTP options" – they are options for the OpenSSH 'sftp' program specifically, whereas Nautilus' GVFS has its own implementation of the SFTP protocol and does not use the 'sftp' CLI tool.

GVFS does use the `ssh` CLI tool as the transport for SFTP, which will honor `~/.ssh/config` settings no matter how it's launched (whether it's for shell, for file transfer, for Git, for Rsync, etc).

So to configure GVFS to only use IPv4 for a specific SFTP server, add the following settings:

```
Host fs.example.com
    AddressFamily inet
```

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed a good solution. However, I've discovered that `AddressFamily inet` option is only applied if I use the host name as spelled in `Host` header, respecting upper/lower case. If I use any other name, even the one from `HostName` field, `inet` option is not applied. Is there any way to enforce IPv4 with a given host regardless of the alias used for connection?

Comment: Since you want to affect IP address usage, the matching _needs_ to happen based on the name, so you'll have to either list all possible variants in the `Host` header, or try using a Match header like `Match canonical host fs.example.com` instead.